# Dynamic change in url in retrofit

Tags: java, android

I want to call this url
http://192.168.122.1/local/date=?user_id=?

I have wrote my api like this

```
@POST("/local")
void create(@Body User user,
                RestCallback<MyCallback> callback);
```

The date and userid parameter is  dynamic and will change at runtime.How I am gonna call this full url using retrofit.Please help me.

Comment: see retorfit documentation it is present there how to send parameters via post or get with retrofit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change it like

```
  @POST("/local")    
  void create(@Query("user_id") String userid,
              @Query("date") String date,
              @Body User user,
              RestCallback<MyCallback> callback);
```

Hope this helps.